# "I lived in" vs. "I have lived in" in context

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

Let's say I lived in the US two years ago and I want to mention the fact that I have the experience of living there without mentioning when I did it. Do I say *I lived in the US* or *I've lived in the US*? For example:

> Person A: I'm going to the US next summer.
>
> Person B: Wow! You'll have quite the experience. **I lived** there./**I've lived** there.

If both are possible in the context, what is the difference in meaning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably wouldn't say "I lived there" unless it was as part of a longer sentence, such as "I lived there for several years".

"I've lived there" also sounds a bit odd here without further context.

By far the most likely and idiomatic wording would be "I used to live there".

Comment: Thank you for the answer! What about if I lived there for a short period of time, would "I've lived there" work? Or would it be better to say "I've lived there for some time" or "I lived there for some time"?

Comment: It would be better to say "I lived there for a while" or "I lived there for a short time".